# Why can't I install an app on my iPad with the correct Deployment Target?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, base-sdk, deployment-target

I have a project for the iPhone, and I'm using an iPad to test it out on. My iPad is running 3.2.

The project has a Base SDK of 4.2 and a Deployment target of 3.2. However, when I try to install it on the iPad, I get the message:

> The Info.plist for application at /Path/AppName.app specifies a minimum OS version of 4.2, which is too high to be installed on MyPad

I've checked both Project Settings and Active Target Settings, and they are bold only in the Project Settings. They both say the correct values.

Any ideas? I'm stumped! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh... I've been stupid. I was changing "Release" instead of "Debug"....

Sorry everyone! Go back to what you were doing! :) *blush*

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Deployment target of 3.1.

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't work :( I need at least 3.2 anyway, I'm embedding fonts.